# Is "keep them looking natural" grammatical?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context

I came across this sentence. Is it grammatical?

> This will keep your face looking beautiful?

It struck me as odd, but I am unable to say it is wrong, because "keep + noun + present participle" seems to be a valid construction, e.g. *keep it going*.

Is there any difference in meaning between that sentence and

> This will keep your face beautiful?

Comment: It's perfectly grammatical. One of the definitions of [keep](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/keep) is "to cause to remain in a given place, situation, or condition".  So "this product *will cause* your lips *to remain* looking natural".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "It will keep your lips looking natural"

That is completely grammatical and idiomatic English.